# AttributeError: 'CatBoostClassifier' object has no attribute 'grid_search'

Tags: python, python-3.x, машинное-обучение, catboost

Выводит ошибку AttributeError: 'CatBoostClassifier' object has no attribute 'grid_search', хотя в документации catboost есть информация о grid_search
https://catboost.ai/docs/concepts/python-reference_catboostclassifier_grid_search.html

```
python
from catboost import CatBoostClassifier as clf
X = df_features.iloc[:, 3:].fillna(0)
y = df_features['fire_type']
cb_clf = clf(iterations = 1000,
                      depth = 5,
                      loss_function = 'MultiClass',
                      #learning_rate = 0.15
                      )
grid = {'learning_rate':[i/100 for i in range(1,100)],
       'l2_leaf_reg': [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]}
grid_search_result = cb_clf.grid_search(grid, 
                                       X=X, 
                                       y=y, 
                                       plot=True)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-ab1608deb638> in <module>
      1 grid = {'learning_rate':[i/100 for i in range(1,100)],
      2        'l2_leaf_reg': [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]}
----> 3 grid_search_result = cb_clf.grid_search(grid, 
      4                                        X=X,
      5                                        y=y,

AttributeError: 'CatBoostClassifier' object has no attribute 'grid_search'
```

Comment: Какая у вас версия CatBoost ?

Comment: Версия CatBoost 0.12.2

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Текущая версия CatBoost на сегодня - `0.18.1`.

Похоже в версии `CatBoost 0.12.2` метод `grid_search` не реализован.

Попробуйте обновить версию `CatBoost`.